# Does $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{tr(A'A)}{N}=0$ imply $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{tr(A)}{N}=0$?

Tags: matrices, limits, trace

$A$ is an $N\times N$ matrix with bounded row and column norms. Does $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{tr(A'A)}{N}=0$ imply  $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{tr(A)}{N}=0$?

I know this is true for finite $N$, but how to prove it when $N\rightarrow\infty$? If this statement is false, can someone give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(B^\ast A)$ is an inner product on $M_n(\mathbb C)$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\frac{\left|\operatorname{tr}(A)\right|}{n}
=\frac{\left|\langle A,I\rangle\right|}{n}
\le\frac{\sqrt{\langle I,I\rangle\, \langle A,A\rangle}}{n}
=\frac{\sqrt{n\operatorname{tr}(A^\ast A)}}{n}
=\sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{tr}(A^\ast A)}{n}}.
$$